# ETL is interpreted or compiled language

Tags: epsilon, model-driven

Is Epsilon transformation language (ETL) `interpreted` or `compiled` language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETL is an interpreted language. Quoting the respective [Epsilon FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/faq/#compiled-or-interpeted):

> All Epsilon languages are interpreted. With the exception of EGL templates which are transformed into EOL before execution, all other languages are supported by bespoke interpreters.

Comment: FYI. This answer is now in the Low Quality review queue. I suggest you [edit] it, to support your statement. Preferably with references to official sources. Without that, your answer may get deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've updated the answer accordingly.